# How to be able keep on sending from client to server without follow the sequence and freeze?

Tags: c#, winforms, client, console-application, system.net.sockets

I'm currently doing an application of chat between a server with a client. It works, but then it can only follow the sequence of starting by [client send to server]->[server send to client again]. If server didn't send it back to client, client will remain freeze. I actually want to make my client able to keep on sending to server without those sequence. Is there any suggestion I can use? Like background worker or what? I tried keypress but it doesn't works well. I will try any suggestion, thanks.
The first code is my server code in console application and the second code is my client code in windows forms application.

```
    namespace TcpIpNewServer
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(8888);
        TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
        serverSocket.Start();
        Console.WriteLine(">> Server started...");
        clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
        Console.WriteLine(">> Accepted connection from client...");

        while ((true))
        {               
            NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();                               
            byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
            networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
            if (bytesFrom[0].ToString() != "0")                                     //listen from client
            {
                string dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$^$~~)("));      //hardcode
                Console.WriteLine("<< Client : " + dataFromClient);
            }

            //var cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
            //if (cki.KeyChar == 't')
            //{                    
                string serverResponse = Console.ReadLine();
                if (serverResponse != null)                                         //write to client
                {
                    Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);
                    networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
                    networkStream.Flush();
                }
            //}
        }
    }
}
}
```

Client code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Msg("Client started...");
        try
        {
            clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);
            NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            label1.Text = "Client Socket Program - Server connected...";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            label1.Text = "Client Socket Program - Server connection failed... Please try again...Make sure server is on...";
        }

    }

    System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
        if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox1.Text != null)                       //write to the server
        {
            //string trimDataText = Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, @"s", "");              
            string cloneTextbox = textBox1.Text + "$^$~~)(";
            Msg("Me: " + textBox1.Text);
            textBox1.Text = ""; 
            byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cloneTextbox);
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();                
        }

        byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];                                      //read from the server
        //if (inStream[0].ToString() != "0")
        //{
            serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
            string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
            Msg2("Server: " + returndata);
        //}   
    }

    private void Msg(string mesg)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + ">> " + mesg;
    }

    private void Msg2(string mesg)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + "<< " + mesg;
    }
```

Comment: @steve yes, that is blocking and made my program freeze

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to switch to async reading/writing ie. `NetworkStream.BeginRead()`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.beginread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx